# Вводные конструкции с постпозитивным номинативом

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

> Я прочитал сценарий, повесть. Ну, в общем, неплохая работа, хорошая.

Неплохая работа — это постпозитивный номинатив? Может ли постпозитивный номинатив сопровождаться вводными конструкциями?

Comment: Кто-то продолжает заминусовывать хорошие вопросы.С меня плюс. По всем признакам, это постпозитивный номинатив. А с чего бы ему не сопровождаться вводными конструкциями? Какие грамматически ограничения даже гипотетически сюда можно приплести?

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд - это не номинатив, так слова "неплохая работа" выступают тут в роли сказуемого. Общий смысл высказывания таков

> Сценарий (подлежащее), который я прочитал - в общем-то, неплохая
>   работа (сказуемое)

Таким образом, считаю правильным рассматривать второе предложение как типичное неполное предложение, подлежащее которого восстанавливается из предыдущего контекста:

> Ну, в общем, [этот сценарий -] неплохая работа, хорошая.